# Adding Wrap Panel in to a Stack Panel

Tags: c#, wpf

Why does this no work? The Stack Panel has default settings Buttons shouldn't be out of border.

```
void AddWrapPanel() {

    WrapPanel myWrapPanel = new WrapPanel();
    myWrapPanel.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Azure;
    myWrapPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    myWrapPanel.Width = 200;
    myWrapPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    myWrapPanel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;

    // Define 3 button elements. The last three buttons are sized at width 
    // of 75, so the forth button wraps to the next line.
    Button btn1 = new Button();
    btn1.Content = "Button 1";
    btn1.Width = 200;
    Button btn2 = new Button();
    btn2.Content = "Button 2";
    btn2.Width = 75;

    // Add the buttons to the parent WrapPanel using the Children.Add method.
    myWrapPanel.Children.Add(btn1);
    myWrapPanel.Children.Add(btn2);
    this.stackPanel1.Children.Add(myWrapPanel);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AddWrapPanel();
}
```

here the XAML

```
  <Window x:Class="AmpelThingy.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="349,276,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <StackPanel Height="214" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,33,0,0" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="392" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

its a simle problem i dont know what more details i can write

Comment: It dosent show up and i use WPF

Comment: Post your XAML, It works for me

Comment: i also  addet this.Show() but didnt helpt

Comment: *i dont know hot to delete comments*... put your mouse cursor at the right side/end (after your name and the edit link (if it is a new comment)) of the comment and a small red delete button should appear. Click it to delete your comment.

Comment: Also, try using XAML like the rest of us and you will avoid all of these problems.

Comment: but then, can you still add stuff dynamic?

Comment: to delete tpoic: ohh.. i was expecting it to be in the edit menu

Comment: Yes you can still add stuff from code.

Comment: @PaulBöttger did you debug it? Did it go into `AddWrapPanel` because without `Button.Click` assigned it won't call your method: `<Button Content="Button" ... Click="button1_Click"/>`

Comment: welllp, didnt expect that he dosent do such a esential thing atumaticaly but big thanks that solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have created a method "button1_Click" but how does WPF know when it should actuallly call it? So, you have to hook buttons click event to "button1_Click" method. You can do it using Click="button1_Click" property. Now your XAML will look like :

```
        <Grid>
            <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="349,276,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
            <StackPanel Height="214" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,33,0,0" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="392" />
        </Grid>
```

Hope this will help you..!

Comment: since visual studio creates automaticaly a event handler i was expecting it to also link to it, that was the problem, thx

Comment: @PaulBöttger OK. Now you have found solution so you should mark this as an answer. So, whenever other person is reading this post, he can find what is solution for this. I also appreciate dkozl's efforts.